# Apollo Client: Upsert mutation only modifies cache on update but not on create

Tags: javascript, react-redux, apollostack, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have an upsert query that gets triggered on either create or update. On update, Apollo integrates the result into the cache but on create it does not.

Here is the query:

```
export const UPSERT_NOTE_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation upsertNote($id: ID, $body: String) {
    upsertNote(id: $id, body: $body) {
      id
      body
    }
  }`
```

My client:

```
const graphqlClient = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface,
  reduxRootSelector: 'apiStore',
  dataIdFromObject: ({ id }) => id
});
```

The response from the server is identical: Both `id` and `body` are returned but Apollo isn't adding new ids into the `data` cache object automatically.

Is it possible to have Apollo automatically add new Objects to `data` without triggering a subsequent fetch?

Here is what my data store looks like:

[image]

**UPDATE**

According to the documentation, the function `updateQueries` is supposed to allow me to push a new element to my list of assets without having to trigger my origin fetch query again.

The function gets executed but whatever is returned by the function is completely ignored and the cache is not modified.

Even if I do something like this:

```
    updateQueries: {
      getUserAssets: (previousQueryResult, { mutationResult }) => {
        return {};
      }
    }
```

Nothing changes.

**UPDATE #2**

Still can't get my assets list to update.

Inside `updateQueries`, here is what my `previousQueryResult` looks like:

```
    updateQueries: {
      getUserAssets: (previousQueryResult, { mutationResult }) => {
        return {
          assets: []
            .concat(mutationResult.data.upsertAsset)
            .concat(previousQueryResult.assets)
        }
      }
    }
```

But regardless of what I return, the data store does not refresh:

[image]

For reference, here is what each `asset` looks like:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto-update of apollo client cache after mutation not affecting existing queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360260/auto-update-of-apollo-client-cache-after-mutation-not-affecting-existing-queries)

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the example [here](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#updateQueries) ?
I would write the updateQueries in the mutate like this:

```
updateQueries: {
  getUserAssets: (previousQueryResult, { mutationResult }) => {
    const newAsset = mutationResult.data.upsertAsset;
    return update(prev, {
      assets: {
        $unshift: [newAsset],
      },
    });
  },  
}
```

Or with object assign instead of update from immutability-helper:

```
updateQueries: {
  getUserAssets: (previousQueryResult, { mutationResult }) => {
    const newAsset = mutationResult.data.upsertAsset;
    return Object.assign({}, prev, {assets: [...previousQueryResult.assets, newAsset]});
  },  
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have tried both of your recommendations and they don't work. I have also followed the link you sent before with no luck. What is happening is that a successful graphql request is made successfully but the newly created asset is not added to the list of assets until I refresh the page. This is definitely mind boggling.

Answer (score 0):

As you state in your update, you need to use `updateQueries` in order to update the queries associated with this mutation. Although your question does not state what kind of query is to be updated with the result of the mutation, I assume you have something like this:

```
query myMadeUpQuery {
  note {
    id 
    body
  }
}
```

which should return the list of notes currently within your system with the id and body of each of the notes. With `updateQueries`, your callback receives the result of the query (i.e. information about a newly inserted note) and the previous result of this query (i.e. a list of notes) and your callback has to return the new result that should be assigned to the query above.

See [here](https://github.com/apollostack/GitHunt-React/blob/master/ui/routes/CommentsPage.js#L184) for an analogous example. Essentially, without the `immutability-helper` that the given example uses, you could write your `updateQueries` callback as follows:

```
updateQueries: {
  myMadeUpQuery: (previousQueryResult, { mutationResult }) => {
    return {
      note: previousQueryResult.note(mutationResult.data.upsertNode),
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Dhaivat. I just update my question with update #2. Still unfortunately can't get this to work properly.