# How to update a state by calling a query when you click a button using react, typescript and graphql?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

i want to update the state on clicking a button.

i initialise the state and gquery the graphql server and when user clicks on add button i want to call the query again to update the state.

```
import { useCreate, useDelete } from '../some/some.mutation-hooks';
import { useGetCount } from '../count/GetCount.query-hooks'; // this is the query hook

function Parent () {
    const { available } = useGetCount();
    const count = available.count;
    create_item = asyc () => {
        try {
            await create({ email: email});
        }

    }

    render = ( ) => {
        return (
            <span>Label Count</span>
            <span>{Count}</span>
            <Button onClick={create_item}>Add</Button>
        )
    }
}
```

Now on clicking Add button, the Count value will not update until page refresh. how can i update this count value without page refresh.

Could someone help me fix this. i am new to using graphql. thanks

Comment: you don't need this abstractions (code?) over useQuery / useMutations ... **all hooks need to be called inside FC on every render**, not by imports, strange idea

Comment: @xadm There's [code generators](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-react-apollo) that create hooks or components for you. Either way, [hooks can be used inside other hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) and this is a perfectly fine way of separating business logic from presentational components.

Comment: You need to provide an `update` or `refetchQueries` option to your hook call. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360260/auto-update-of-apollo-client-cache-after-mutation-not-affecting-existing-queries/60362315#60362315) for additional details.

Comment: @DanielRearden I know, but I don't see `useCreate` used, where is `create` defined ?

Comment: @DanielRearden ... and he knows a general rules / how it works (see earlier questions) but lost in customizing generated code?